# Rails 5, How to name two models with an associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given the following two models:

```
ChefPosition (Executive, Sous, etc...)
Skills (Creativity, speed, quality)
```

I'm working to create a table that defines what skills are defined per ChefPosition. So far I have:

```
ChefPositionSkill (chef_position_id, skill_id)
```

In the Rails 5 world, am I naming the models correctly? If so, what would be the right way to name a controller that returns the skills per ChefPosition, something like:

```
ChefPositionSkillController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @ChefPositionSkills = Skill.where(:chef_position => params[:chef_position_id]
    render json: @ChefPositionSkills, status: status
  end
end
```

Is this right?

Comment: If you set up the has_many through model as `ChefPositionSkill` the Controller for that model would be `ChefPositionSkillsController`

Comment: Which do you recommend? What's the right Rails way to do it?

Comment: If you need specific information about the association as @bkunzi01 puts it (i.e. skill rank or points) do [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).   If it is just a simple association (no extra information besides the fact that they are associated), do a [HABTM association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).  And if it is a HABTM association, a model/controller isn't necessary just the DB table

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGorman. A `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship is the simplest and likely all you will need. You don't need a model and there's even a migration shortcut for creating the join table. See the first part of [this tutorial](https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/3451-Has-Many-Through-and-Has-and-Belongs-to-Many-in-Rails-5) for the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conventions can take a while to get used to, but in general:

You would have the following tables and foreign keys (plural):

```
chef_positions
* id
* name
* ...

skills
* id
* name
* ...

chef_position_skills
* id
* chef_position_id
* skill_id
```

Then you could define models for each table with their associations (singular):

```
class ChefPosition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chef_position_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :chef_position_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chef_position_skills
  has_many :chef_positions, through: :chef_position_skills
end

class ChefPositionSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chef_position
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

If you wanted an endpoint to access all of the chef position skills for a given position, you might create a **nested** route in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :chef_positions, only: [] do
  resources :chef_position_skills, only: [:index]
end
```

This would define a route at `/chef_positions/:chef_position_id/chef_position_skills`.

Then you could create a controller (plural) to find the list of chef position skills given a chef position:

```
class ChefPositionSkillsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    chef_position = ChefPosition.find(params[:chef_position_id])
    render json: chef_position.chef_position_skills
  end
end
```

Comment: Is INDEX the right kind of method given it requires a param?

Comment: @AnApprentice yes, but the parameter is part of the path for nested routes.
`subdomain.domain.com/chef_positions/41/chef_position_skills`
would fill `params[:chef_position_id]` with `41`

Answer (score 2):

First thing that jumps out to me is the "ChefPositionSkillController" should be pluralized to follow Rails conventions so should be "`ChefPositionSkillsController`".  Also, if you're just planning on relating a many-to-many with ChefPositions and Skills you're fine naming the join table ChefPositionSkill (Just remember you can change this but the join table must be the combined names of the two tables in lexical order which is what you have here).  Most people however, now use a "has_many through" relationship in that you can add additional details to your join table and not be limited to just the id columns.  This would benefit you if you ever decide that a chef, with a certain skillset, should also have a rank or priority etc.

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful.. Any feedback on the controller... Should the index method be used to return all the skills per position?

Comment: Yes that would make sense.